# How to replace newlines/linebreaks with a single space, but only if they are inside of start/end regexes?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, unix, replace

I have an extremely big (many GBs in size) file that looks like

```
[x data1 
 data2 data3
 data4 y]
[a data5 data 6 
 data7  
  data 8 b>
[x data y]
...and so on
```

How to replace newlines (which might be surrounded by spaces) with a single space, but only if they are inside of `[x` and `y]` regex parts? So, the output should be

```
[x data1 data2 data3 data4 y]
[a data5 data 6 
 data7  
  data 8 b>
[x data y]
```

Comment: Have you tried something? are you reading the file line by line? also in what programming language?

Comment: I have no idea what tool is designed to solve such problems. I tried to do this with `gawk`, but I couldn't write the logic correctly, and I think that awk is not supposed to solve this type of problems.

Comment: have you written anything? if yes, post it

Comment: I don't know how to specify that **any newline** must be replaced with something only if they are inside of two regexes. `sed -e 's/regex1.*?\n.*?regex2/ /p'` is not enough.

Comment: Will you consider using perl instead? (should be very simple to solve this)

Comment: I don't mind using Perl for this, but I am not a Perl programmer, so I did not even try to write the code :) And by the way, I think the input should be read line by line, without consuming too much memory. I don't want such a big file to be loaded into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `awk` as:

```
awk '/\[x/{f=1} {if(f)printf "%s",$0; else print $0;} /y\]/{print ""; f=0}'
```

Output:

```
[x data1  data2 data3 data4 y]
[a data5 data 6 
 data7  
  data 8 b>
[x data y]
```

You can also simplify to:

```
awk '/\[x/,/y\]/{ORS=""; if(/y\]/) ORS="\n";}{print}'
```

Output:

```
[x data1  data2 data3 data4 y]
[a data5 data 6 
 data7  
  data 8 b>
[x data y]
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is not using direct regular expression, it is a perl script that runs on the input file line by line and performs the logic requested by the OP.

You can modify the script as you wish to achieve a slightly different logic.

```
my $inFile;
my $inFile = $ARGV[0];

my $fh;
open($fh, $inFile) || die;

my $outFh;
open($outFh, ">out.txt") || die;

my $inStr = 0;
my $finalStringBuf = "";

while (my $row = <$fh>) 
{
    chomp $row;

    if ($row =~ /^\[x/)
    {   
        $row =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; # ltrim and rtrim (remove whitespace before and after the string)

        if ($row =~ /y\]$/)
        {
            # if the row ends with a 'y]' also, just print the row
            print $outFh $row . "\n";   #print to output
        }
        else
        {
            # if row starts with '[x'
            $inStr = 1;
            $finalStringBuf = $row; # reset the buffer to a new string
        }
    }
    elsif ($row =~ /y\]$/)
    {
        $row =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; # ltrim and rtrim (remove whitespace before and after the string)

        # if row ends with 'y]'
        $inStr = 0;
        $finalStringBuf .= ' ' . $row; # concate the last section of our string with a space between

        $finalStringBuf =~ s/\n//g; # replace \n with a space       
        print $outFh $finalStringBuf . "\n";
    }
    elsif ($inStr == 1)
    {       
        # concate the string to our buffer
        $finalStringBuf .= $row;
    }
    else
    {
        print $outFh $row . "\n";   #print to output
    }
}

close ($fh);
close ($outFh);
```

Comment: What does `my $inFile = $ARGV[0];` mean? Why not writing input file name right here? And how to write this code in console? It seems I cannot use `$ perl 'code' path/to/input.txt` because quotes are already used in the code...

Comment: you easily replace the `$ARGV[0];` with a literal filename, that is not a problem